# QuickTime Player 10.5 (928.50) Mojave - Controls Stuck, Always Visible

Tags: bug, quicktime, mojave

Latest version Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75) did not fix it.

[image]

Can't get the controls out of the way.

Mouse pointer is also always present.

Comment: What mac do you use?Didn't see a similar problem.Will it be your mouse  or trackpad problem?

Comment: I assume if you click inside the player window (not on the media controls), the controls don't go away?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), clicking doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling Accessability Keyboard fixed the problem.